# How can i audit a MEAN project to find memory leak problems?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, compilation, heap-memory

I have a MEAN project using Angular SSR. A cron is being called and running on the server.ts file but since I added few more lines, it gives me ""FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" when I compile for dev in the same laptop that was not causing this error. I have tried some solutions like "set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" and even to 6144 but I still got the same error. I have tried to add that parameter to environment variables on Windows but no success. Also, sometimes I get the same error when trying to compile in my 64-GB-Ram home pc, so I have my doubts if it is really a memory problem.

It is not clear to me what is causing the mistakes because sometimes i comment the whole cron import in the server.ts file, but still get the error.

I am looking for a way to audit or scan what is causing the high usage of memory or, in general, a way to detect possible optimizations on this project.